# getting more vertical divs and separated footer

Tags: css, html, width

Since hours I'm trying to get what I posted on the image but I can't reach that...
Why are those CSS so un-userfriendy?

e.g. If the 2 divs in green are not the same lenght, my footer will be posted just below the shortest green div.

I'd like also if all the content is resizable for 1000px narrower windows.

Thank you!

So... I discover I can't post images...

I try to "draw" here:

```
---------------------------------------------------
|                 DIV                             |
---------------------------------------------------
|                  DIV                            |
--------------------------------------------------
|                  DIV                            |
---------------------------------------------------
|            some white space                     |
-----------------------   -------------------------
|                     |  |                        |
|                     |S |                        |
|                     |P |                        |
|                     |A |                        |
|                     |C |                        |
|                     |E |                        |
|DIV (about 30% width)|  | DIV (rest of width)    |
|                     |  |                        |
|                     |  |                        |
|                     |  |                        |
|                     |  |                        |
|                     |  |                        |
|                     |  |                        |
|_____________________|  |________________________|
|               some white space                  |
|_________________________________________________|
|                   div for footer etc.           |
|_________________________________________________|
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ works much better to show your problem and get help.

Comment: Unfortunately I included on my DIVs content from others files with php. So have all together for jsfiddle is a bit difficult, sorry!

Comment: Well it still all renders up as HTML! Hard to help if we don't see your CSS and related HTML (just need the relevant code, not everything). Sounds like a positioning and/or float issue.

Comment: means you want this type of design?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is the HTML for you layout

```
<div>
  <div class="div1">
  </div>
    <div class="div1">
  </div><div class="div1">
  </div>
    <div class="left">
  </div>    <div class="right">
  </div>
    <div class="footer">
  </div>
</div>
```

And following is the CSS for it.

```
.div1
{
    width:100%;  
    border:1px solid black;
    height:50px;
    margin:5px;
}
.left
{
 width:30%;   
 border:1px solid black;
 margin:5px;
 height:50px;
 float:left;
}
.right
{
 width:60%;
 border:1px solid black;
 height:50px;
 float:right;
 margin:5px;

}
.footer
{
     width:100%;  
     border:1px solid black;
     height:50px;
    overflow: auto; 
    margin:5px;

}
```

Change the heights. Or there is no need to change heights if you are adding content in the DIVs they will get height automatically.

[See Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/xyJ8J/)

Comment: Thank you for the reply!
Whitout content is working well, but take a look if I put some contents: http://jsfiddle.net/fbwvq/
The footer is no loger the footer... The content is going between the two others div. That's what I don't want!

Comment: @Perocat you have missed overflow:both. and another thing is you have not removed the height:50px; from the divs where you are adding data. Because height property override the content height. See update jsfiddle.net/fbwvq/1/

Comment: Thank you! Now it's working.
If I'd like to set the page width to 1000px and post the divs on the center, what should I do?

e.g.:
Screen resolution: 1920x1080
Page look like:

space with nothing (in THIS case 460px) - div and body alligned center 1000px width - space with nothing (in THIS case 460px).

If I set body{width:1000px;} all is moving left...
I'd also like that, just like now, if the window is narrower than 1000px no horizontal scroll bar is coming, but that the div auto resize.
Thank you!

Comment: Ok I get all by myself doing some test! Thank you again